# Is it possible to individually view URL variables in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I got a request to implement a way to individually view variables in the URL sent to Google Analytics.

For example say this URL is sent to Google Analytics

```
/testsite/test?gender=male&ethnicity=european
```

Is it possible to extract the variables "gender" and "european" from the URL and view them in Google Analytics?

Let's say the following URLs are sent to Google Analytics

```
/testsite/test?gender=male&ethnicity=nativeamerican

/testsite/test?gender=female&ethnicity=european

/testsite/test?gender=female&ethnicity=africanamerican

/testsite/test?gender=male&ethnicity=european

/testsite/test?gender=female&ethnicity=european
```

Ideally I would like to be able to say the URL /testsite/test.html was sent 5 times and 2/5 were male, 3/5 were female, 1/5 indicated africanamerican, 1/5 indicated nativeamerican, indicated 3/5 indicated white.

Is it possible to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks:)

PS - This can be done at the code level or at the analytics level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with analytics but in the javascript part you should detect first of all the var and then send the specific event to analytics. For example:

```
      if(gender == 'male'){
        ga('send', 'pageview', '/testsite/test1/male');
      }else{
        ga('send', 'pageview', '/testsite/test1/female');
      }
```

With the analytics I can't help you because I have never done this part of the process.

I hope it helps you